# Readable stream's read method does not return null

Tags: javascript, node.js

The doc for `readableStream.read(size)` says,

> if size bytes are not available, then it will return null.

To test this i did:

```
// in test.js
process.stdin.on('readable', function(){
  var d = this.read(30);
  if (d) console.log(d.toString());
});

$ (echo abc; sleep 1; echo def; sleep 1; echo ghi) | node test.js
```

The output was the following:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

I expected the code to print `null`, as the `size(30)` was greater than the bytes written. Why does it not print `null`?

As per @hexacyanide's comments I rewrote the code as below, and ran the test again:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var d = this.read(300);
  if (d === null) {
    console.log("NULL")
  } else {
    console.log(d.toString());
  }
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
  console.log('END EVENT')
});
```

Test output:

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
abc
def
ghi

END EVENT
```

I can now understand the output till the 3 `NULL's`.
After that I have few questions based on the output:

1. Why did I get `abc\ndef\nghi` as the output for my first test? I'm asking this because even after pushing `abcdefghi` to the stream, its buffer length is still 9. So if I read at any give time, the read operation should return `null`. To be sure, I set the read size to 300.
2. How does the stream know that I have completed all my pushes?

Comment: Do you have any other code to show? Using your setup, I ran a few tests, and `d` is `null`, as expected. Do note that you shouldn't expect `null` to be printed, because of your `if` statement. Tested on NodeJS `v0.10.16`.

Comment: you should check for `null` using `if(d === null)`

Comment: @hexacyanide, i have updated the question as per your comments. Please have a look at it. vinayr, Thanks for your advice, i have incorporated your null check code too in the updated question

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to reproduce your problem, I assumed that you had already resumed the `process.stdin` stream, which is paused by default. I later found out that when leaving that bit out, I got the unintended output that you were getting. This is what the NodeJS documentation states:

> The stdin stream is paused by default, so one must call
>   `process.stdin.resume()` to read from it.

Before adding the `readable` listener, I just used `resume()` on the stream and got the intended output.

I don't know if I'm correct, but in your case, I'd assume that `readable` is firing each time `echo` is run, and `read()` is reading nothing in those cases, but when `stdin` is closed, `read()` just reads everything. Here's my test code and results:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  console.log('fire');
  console.log(process.stdin.read(300));
}).on('end', function(){
  console.log("END EVENT")
});
```

I then ran that code like so: `(echo abc; sleep 1; echo def; sleep 1; echo ghi) | node test.js` and got these results:

```
fire
null
fire
null
fire
null
fire
<Buffer 61 62 63 0a 64 65 66 0a 67 68 69 0a>
END EVENT
```

When testing after resuming the `stdin` stream, `readable` fires four times, and `read(300)` properly returns `null`.

Comment: thanks very much for taking time. I have one note on your answer. AFAIK When you call resume or pause on a stream it goes to flowing mode making that stream to emit only the data event, instead of readable event. Coming to by question, im clear till 3rd 'fire' event. how was it possible for node to read the stream after the 3rd 'fire' event, as the stream is not filled with 300 bytes yet.

Comment: +1, for the explanation. Sorry i could not mark it as answered.